# Local Variables in AspectJ

Tags: java, compiler-construction, aspectj

I'm implementing an invariants extension to the java language. I'm implementing the parser for my new language and annotated AST as an intermediate representation. Now I'm thinking of using AspectJ to control where to inject code in a visit to AST to control the variables but I detect a problem. AspectJ doesn't have a joinpoint to local variables. Is there any extension to aspectj or other aspect programming framework with this functionality?

Regards

Comment: I'd like to hear more about your requirements. There are join points for variable access; I wonder if they might help.

Comment: the join points for variable its for class variables and not for variables declared inside a method for example. I want make invariants for the 2 types of variables.

Comment: That's true. @kriegaex's idea below, of using lower-level bytecode instrumentation, makes sense to me. I've done some work with ASM before, and would be interested in an open-source project like yours.

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Local variable access is not exposed as a joinpoint in AspectJ, and I do not know of any extension to AspectJ to do that.

Maybe lower-level bytecode instrumentation libraries like ASM could be helpful in your case. With ASM you can work on JVM byte code level.

Comment: thanks for the reply. At the momment i cant find anything useful for this