# Get the name of the response object through AOP

Tags: java, aop, javaagents

Using AOP I know using java 8 and a pointcut it is now possible to get the names of a methods method parameters through AOP.

My question is, is it also possible to get the name of the object being returned?

**Update - Adding code example:**

I'm trying to log the name of the object being returned from a method

```
    /**
     * Log the return value of all methods in the package service.impl
     * @param pjp
     * @param returnValue
     */
    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(public * com.bla.core.service.impl.*.*(..))", returning = "returnValue")
    public void debugAfter(JoinPoint pjp, Object returnValue) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug(getAuditEndMessage(pjp, returnValue));
        }
    }


    private String getAuditEndMessage(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object returnValue) {
        String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        String className = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName();

        //Assuming every object has the toString method overriden
        //In reality there is more logic than this
        String returnValueStr = String.valueOf(returnValue);

        String returnValueObjectName = //Trying to find some way of finding this value

        //Ex: "[End][CategoryServiceImpl][getCategory]Ouput: [category=[id=1][name=Test Category][description=Test Description]]
        String returnStr = "[End][" + className + "][" + methodName + "]Ouput: [" + returnValueObjectName + "=" + returnValueStr + "]"

        return returnStr;
    }
```

So if I had a method:

```
    public ExampleCategory getCategory(int categoryId){
        ExampleCategory category = exampleCategoryDao.read(categoryId);
        return category;
    }
```

I want the output string to contain the name of the object being returned:

[End][CategoryServiceImpl][getCategory]Ouput: [**category**=[id=1][name=Test Category][description=Test Description]]

I can get the names of the input parameters with the new java 8 functionality, but I don't know how to do this with the return value.

**Update 2:**

After typing this all up, I realized that if this is possible, there could also be weird cases like:

```
    public ExampleCategory getCategory(int categoryId){
        return exampleCategoryDao.read(categoryId);
    }
```

I could just print the returning class name in those cases. I would still like to know if it is possible to do what I'm asking above.

Comment: (Returned) objects do not have names, only class members or local variables do. What exactly is your use case? Please show some code and describe what you actually want to achieve and why.

Comment: Objects don't have names. Unclear what your'e asking.

Comment: I think this idea is maybe a bit too complicated.  Why not just slap a `toString()` method on the return variable and use that in the audit log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already said in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15805822/1082681), AspectJ has no knowledge about local variables, only about non-static or static member variables. So the answer to your question is no.

Even if that was possible, I do not see any added value in knowing local variable names. There you are far beyond the concept of AOP (implementing cross-cutting concerns) and rather within the realm of a debugger. Besides, the very concept of **local** variables (and even the term itself!) is about their locality. Other than methods they are not part of the contract of a class but completely internal to its implementation.

By the way, the advice name `@AfterReturning` is a hint as to its purpose: get some info and do something **after** a method has returned its result. You want to know some internal method state just before it returns the result.